# Excel VBA: Delete row if match with value in combobox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of projects on a combobox in a sheet which is Filled by a range from another sheet. I can already add a project. Now I would like to delete a project name if the combobox value is equal to the value in a range on another sheet.  I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
Dim ProjNameWS As Worksheet
Set ProjNameWS = Sheets("Project Names")
Dim MainWS As Worksheet
Set MainWS = Sheets("Main")


Application.ScreenUpdating = False


ProjValue = Me.CmbProjName.Value
LR = ProjNameWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

For y = 1 To LR



If ProjValue = ProjNameWS.Cells(y, 1) Then

    ProjNameWS.Rows(y).Delete

End If

Next y

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

By the way, I am using activeX Combobox in a sheet

[image]

This is what the error looks when I removed the On Error Resume Next:

[image]
[image]

Comment: please expand on the `but it doesn't work`.  what is it doing that is in error?  Do you get an error? if so on which line?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I don't get any error, it just doesn't work. I also tried to change the ProjNameWS.Rows(y).Delete to a message box so I would know if it matches. But it also doesn't prompt anything.

Comment: first thing; remove the `On Error Resume Next` run it and tell us where the error is.

Comment: for deleting rows you must always go backwards: `For y = LR to 1 Step -1`

Comment: I have now edited and provided the error when I removed the On Error Resume Next.

Comment: I tested your code without "on error resume next", and the errors were that the variable ProjValue, LR and y were not declared. I have modified your code and and the declaration of these variables, and it worked. Sorry, I cannot see the images you added to the question

Comment: This works fine for me on filling on the Combobox with range without declaring the ProjValue, LR and y. When I tried to reverse (to delete this time) i got the error then. 

My combobox is in a sheet.

Comment: Are the projects named the same in colonne 1 and in the ComboBox? Verify please? or perhaps you need to add functions like "UCASE" or trim the strings?

Comment: Try adding the sheet where the combobox is in front of it. Like `ProjNameWS.CmbProjName.Value`

Comment: Yes, they are the same. Actually the combobox is already auto-populated by with a range. Now, what I would like to do is to reverse. That if the combobox value selected is equal to value in range(filled my combobox). Then it will delete. 
@Moacir I tried to add, but it says method or data member not found.

Comment: Just to make sure, the combobox name is actually `CmbProjName`right?

Comment: Yes, the name is `CmbProjName`.

Comment: Found it. Try `ProjValue = ProjNameWS.OLEObjects("CmbProjName").Object.Value` instead of `ProjValue = Me.CmbProjName.Value`

Comment: Can you please put it as an answer? As I will mark it as an answer. I tried and it worked! Never realized that I missed something that one.

Comment: It's weird!!! It worked for me without this "OLEObjects"!!!

Comment: Yes, weird! Because in my code auto-populate combobox with range, it works even without the `OLEObjects`. But when I tried to do something different like ("Delete"), it doesn't.

Comment: Will put as an answer. Sorry for the delay, it was lunch time haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to treat it as an object

Replace `ProjValue = Me.CmbProjName.Value` with `ProjValue = ProjNameWS.OLEObjects("CmbProjName").Object.Value` and it will work.